# Infinite loop in kotlin using for loop?

Tags: for-loop, kotlin, while-loop, infinite-loop

In java we can write infinite loop using both `while` and `for`

```java
for(;;){
  // doesn't stop[infinite loop] 
}
```

and using `while`

```java
while(true){
  // doesn't stop[infinite loop] 
}
```

the syntax for kotlin's `while` loop for creating `infinite loop` is the same.

How do I create an infinite loop using `for` loop just like the example I wrote above(equivalent code) using kotlin.

Thank you!

Comment: Why would you need an alternate way to do it other than `while(true)`?

Comment: @Tenfour04 just out of curiosity. Since I am new to kotlin I am studying referencing my prior knowledge I had in java. That's all.

Comment: `while (true)` is readable that is even used in pseudo codes, I don't think any confusing syntax is better.

Comment: @Tenfour04 because `while (true)` is ugly and I'm used to programming language with a more elegant form of the endless loop.

Comment: @Martin, out of curiosity, can you tell me what language that is? I’ve never encountered anything more elegant than `while(true)` in any of the languages I’ve learned.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ada: `loop … end loop`. No `true`, no `;;`.  And @th0masb answer is pretty close to that and he mentions rust. Indeed rust has a loop command as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no easy syntax, but you could generate an infinite sequence with [`generateSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html):

```
for (i in generateSequence(0) { it }) {

}
```

Comment: I got a warning `Names _, __, ___, ..., are reserved in Kotlin` in my `IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3` then I replaced  `_` with `i` and worked well. Thought I was looking for an equivalent code `for(;;){}` but Thanks.

Comment: This is as close to equivalent as you can get in Kotlin. Kotlin for loops work exclusively with iterables.

Answer (score 3):

You can get something like the loop keyword in rust with the following:

```kotlin
fun loop(action: () -> Unit) {
  while(true)
    action()
}

// To use
loop {
  println("Not going to stop!")
}
```

Comment: even better, make it an inline function with crossinline parameter